# Batch export of org-mode files from the command line

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Assume that I have in a certain directory several `org-mode` files: `foo1.org`, `foo2.org`, etc. I would like to have a script (maybe a makefile) that I could invoke something like

```
$ generate-pdfs
```

and `foo1.pdf`, `foo2.pdf`, etc. will be generated.

I thought that something like `emacs --batch --eval <MAGIC>` is a good start, but I don't know the magic.

A solution that is solely *inside* emacs could be of interest as well.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

As you said, Emacs has the `--batch` option to perform operations with Emacs from the shell. In addition to that, you can use the `-l` flag to load Emacs Lisp code from a file and execute it, and the `-f` flag to execute a single Lisp function.

Here is a basic example, which exports a single org-mode file to HTML:

```
emacs myorgfile.org --batch -f org-html-export-to-html --kill
```

Perhaps you want something more advanced like exporting/publishing a full org-mode project. I do not have sample code for that, but it should not be too complicated.

I also have a sample Makefile I wrote some time ago to export all org-mode files in the directory to HTML (and also copy the HTML files to another directory):

```
OUT_DIR=/some/output/dir/html
# Using GNU Make-specific functions here
FILES=$(patsubst %.org,$(OUT_DIR)/%.html,$(wildcard *.org))

.PHONY: all clean install-doc

all: install-doc

install-doc: $(OUT_DIR) $(FILES)

$(OUT_DIR):
        mkdir -v -p $(OUT_DIR)

%.html: %.org
        emacs $< --batch -f org-html-export-to-html--kill

$(OUT_DIR)/%.html: %.html
        install -v -m 644 -t $(OUT_DIR) $<
        rm $<

clean:
        rm *.html
```

EDIT:

With Org-mode 8 and the new export engine the function for HTML export has changed.

To make the previous examples work with Org 7 or older, replace `org-html-export-to-html` with `org-export-as-html`.

Comment: The `--batch` implies `-q` that in turn doesn't load my `.emacs`. How can I tell emacs to load a **specific** init file?

Comment: I guess you could use `--batch -l my_init_file.el -f org-latex-export-to-pdf` which would load your init file and then call the export function.

Comment: Also the shorthand that I used, having the target file as the first argument to `emacs`, is not the cleanest way to do it. The correct way to do it would rather be `emacs --batch --visit myorgfile.org -f […]`. This would allow you to process several files with the same command (by adding other `--visit` options in the command)

Comment: `emacs -q` disabled the loading of newer version of `org` (which I installed using `ELPA`). Therefore, I had to use the `-l` option and load an init file which had `(package-initialize)`. This allowed to use the newer version of `org` in `batch` mode.

Answer (score 3):

I expect to publish (by the end of this week-end) OrgMk, a suite of Makefile and standalone Bash scripts (usable as well under Cygwin) just to do that!  Even more: generation of HTML, Ascii, Beamer, etc.

You'll find it on my GitHub account: https://github.com/fniessen/ (where I already have Emacs configuration files, color themes and other stuff such as an Org Babel refcard -- in progress).

Answer (score 2):

Mark a few org files in `dired` and call this:

```
(defun dired-org-to-pdf ()
  (interactive)
  (mapc
   (lambda (f)
     (with-current-buffer
         (find-file-noselect f)
       (org-latex-export-to-pdf)))
   (dired-get-marked-files)))
```

If you know what async is, wrap the call as it can take a while.

### update:

Here's a version that combines the awesome `dired` approach with the lame
other one:)

```
(defun dired-org-to-pdf ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((files
         (if (eq major-mode 'dired-mode)
             (dired-get-marked-files)
           (let ((default-directory (read-directory-name "dir: ")))
             (mapcar #'expand-file-name 
                     (file-expand-wildcards "*.org"))))))
    (mapc
     (lambda (f)
       (with-current-buffer
           (find-file-noselect f)
         (org-latex-export-to-pdf)))
     files)))
```

Comment: +1. But I want something more automatic. Maybe this function can ask for a directory and then process all `.org`s in the given directory?

Comment: It's doable. Although for me `dired` is the default state. Do you know that you can mark all org files in `dired` with `*%org`?