# ox-hugo github actions : Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function org-hugo-export-wim-to-md) Error: Process completed with exit code 255

Tags: emacs, github-actions, hugo

Im trying to deploy my hugo site on github actions. Im using the following github action which does the following :

1.On Ubuntu

2.Setup up emacs

3.git clone ox-hugo package

4.ox-hugo package should convert my .org files to .md

5. setup and build using Hugo and deploy

https://gist.github.com/shwetarkadam/d890b7054b65fe21b63609ca03650bdc

I'm facing an issue on step 4 where I encounter the following error on GitHub action :

```
 Run emacs ./config.org --batch -L ./ox-hugo -L ox-hugo.el --eval="(org-hugo-export-wim-to-md t)" --kill
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function org-hugo-export-wim-to-md)
  (org-hugo-export-wim-to-md t)
  eval((org-hugo-export-wim-to-md t) t)
  command-line-1(("./config.org" "-L" "./ox-hugo" "-L" "ox-hugo.el" "--eval=(org-hugo-export-wim-to-md t)" "--kill"))
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

Approaches tried till now :

1. Changing (org-hugo-export-wim-to-md t) to (org-hugo-export-wim-to-md :all-subtrees)
2. Adding the expression  (org-hugo-export-wim-to-md :all-subtrees) in single quotes and double quotes.
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

I happened to be working on a similar problem today.  I had searched for guidance on it and I stumbled across [Batch export of org-mode files from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22072773/batch-export-of-org-mode-files-from-the-command-line) which led me to [fniessen/orgmk](https://github.com/fniessen/orgmk) and in [orgmk.el](https://github.com/fniessen/orgmk/blob/master/site-lisp/orgmk.el) in particular.
After experimenting in my `*scratch*` buffer and asking Emacs' various help facilities a few questions, I bludgeoned my way to a standalone file containing Emacs Lisp code that appears to work independently of my initialization files.

```
$ touch export.el

$ emacs -q --batch -l export.el
Designating package sites
Designating package site melpa-stable => https://stable.melpa.org/packages/
Designating package site melpa => https://melpa.org/packages/
Designating package site gnu => https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/
Installing package ox-hugo
Setting ‘package-selected-packages’ temporarily since "emacs -q" would overwrite customizations
‘ox-hugo’ is already installed
Exporting org subtrees to hugo from content.org
1 files scanned, 0 files contains IDs, and 0 IDs found.
[ox-hugo] 1/ Exporting ‘Redacted site title’ ..
[ox-hugo] 2/ Exporting ‘Posts’ ..
[ox-hugo] 3/ Exporting ‘Redacted post title’ ..
[ox-hugo] Exported 3 subtrees from content.org in 0.510s (0.170s avg)
Exporting all org subtrees in all files in /redacted/directory

$ find content -newer export.el
content
content/_index.md
content/posts
content/posts/redacted-post-title.md
content/posts/_index.md
```

(Some names have been changed to protect the guilty er um I mean innocent.)

The file `export.el` contains:

```elisp
(defvar my/package-archives
  (list
   (cons "melpa-stable" "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/")
   (cons "melpa" "https://melpa.org/packages/")
   (cons "gnu" "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")))

(defvar my/packages-to-install '(ox-hugo))

(defun my/designate-package-site (site)
  (message "Designating package site %s => %s" (car site) (cdr site))
  (add-to-list 'package-archives site t))

(defun my/designate-package-sites ()
  (message "Designating package sites")
  (mapcar #'my/designate-package-site my/package-archives))

(defun my/install-package (pkg)
  (message "Installing package %s" pkg)
  (ignore-errors (package-install pkg)))

(when (locate-library "package")
  (require 'package)
  (my/designate-package-sites)
  (package-initialize)
  (unless package-archive-contents (package-refresh-contents))
  (mapcar #'my/install-package my/packages-to-install))

(defun my/batch-ox-hugo-file (file)
  (message "Exporting org subtrees to hugo from %s" file)
  (let ((all-subtrees t)
    (any-visibility nil))
    (with-current-buffer (find-file-noselect file)
      (org-hugo-export-wim-to-md all-subtrees any-visibility))))
  
(defun my/batch-ox-hugo-directory (directory)
  (message "Exporting all org subtrees in all files in %s" directory
  (let ((default-directory (expand-file-name directory)))
    (mapcar #'my/batch-ox-hugo-file
        (file-expand-wildcards "*.org")))))

(my/batch-ox-hugo-directory default-directory)
```

The execution environment where I developed this is Emacs 28.2 on FreeBSD 13.1.

I haven't tried it out with Github Actions yet, but that's my next step.